# Should I backshift second conditionals in reported speech?

Tags: conditional-constructions, backshifting

Consider this sentence, please (taken from the English Grammar Secrets website):

> If I **had** millions dollars, I **would** give a lot to charity.

If we used it in reported speech, would it remain the same, or would we have to use *had had* and *would have*, as in third conditionals?

> He said that if he **had** millions dollars, he **would** give a lot to charity.
>
> He said that if he **had had** millions dollars, he **would have** given a lot to charity.

This question occurred to me while reading [this article](http://www.grammaring.com/as-if-as-though) on *as if / as though*. According to it, if the verb of an *as if* or *as though* clause is already in the past tense, it doesn't change.

Comment: "Second conditionals" are not usually backshifted in reported speech, but they can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the same [website.](http://www.grammaring.com/second-conditional-in-indirect-speech) 
If it is possible for him in the future to have a million dollars, then you would use his words, no changes. However, if not possible, then you would backshift it.